# Ionic 2 clearing App cache on logout

Tags: authentication, caching, ionic-framework, ionic2

My login function consists of a http request (an irrelevant one just for the check) with the entered credentials. This way I can resolve the request or get a rejection which I handle by not pushing the next component with the NavController onto the stack.

On logout, the credentials, which are saved in the Ionic Storage, are deleted. Now starts the problem: Any credentials that are saved now in the storage seems not to be used by the login request as the request doesn't throw an Auth exception. Only after clearing the Browser cache it works again.

This all happened by serving the app in a web browser and on the phone.

How is it possible to clear the App cache (not only the View/Component cache) with Ionic 2 to prevent this behaviour? There is no documentation or question concerning this problem existent at the moment.

Auth Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

HAS_LOGGED_IN = 'hasLoggedIn';

constructor(private storage: Storage) {
    // this.rest = rest;
    console.log('auth');
}

setCredentials(credentials) {
    this.storage.set('username', credentials.username);
    this.storage.set('password', credentials.password);
}

logout(): void {
    this.storage.remove('username');
    this.storage.remove('password');
    this.storage.remove(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN);
}

hasLoggedIn() {
    return this.storage.get(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN).then( value => {
        console.log('hasLoggedIN value: ' + value);
        return value === true;
    });
}
}
```

Login Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

    model: any;
    HAS_LOGGED_IN: string = 'hasLoggedIn';

    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,
                private viewCtrl: ViewController,
                private auth: AuthService,
                private toastCtrl: ToastController,
                private rest: RestService,
                private storage: Storage) {

    }
    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.model = {};
    }

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.viewCtrl.showBackButton(false);
        this.displayTab(false);
    }

    login() {
        console.log(this.model);
        console.log('login() claled');
        this.displayTab(true);
        this.auth.setCredentials(this.model);

        this.rest.getEntryPoint().then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.storage.set(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN, true);
            this.navCtrl.push(OverviewPage);
        }).catch(err => {
            this.storage.set(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN, false);
            console.log('Error:');
            console.log(err);
            this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(this.navCtrl);
                console.log('pushed login 1');
            });
        });
    }

    validate(items: boolean) {

        if (items) {
            let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                message: 'Passwort und Benutzername sind zwingend',
                duration: 3000,
                position: 'bottom',
            });

            toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
                console.log('Dismissed toast');
            });

            toast.present();
        }
    }

    private displayTab(display: boolean) {
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.tabbar');

        if (elements != null) {
            Object.keys(elements).map((key) => {
                elements[key].style.transform = display ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(70px)';
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Intercepting Http methods (this service is used in another service that makes the actual Rest calls):

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService {

    constructor(@Inject(Http) private http: Http, private storage: Storage) {
        this.http = http;
        console.log('interceptor');
    }

    get(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let headers = new Headers();
            this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers).then(() => {
                return this.http.get(url, {
                    headers: headers,
                }).subscribe(data => {
                    resolve(data.json());
                }, err => {
                    reject(err);
                });
            });
        });
    }

    put(url: string, attributes?) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let headers = new Headers();
            this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers).then(() => {
                return this.http.put(url, (attributes) ? attributes : {}, {
                    headers: headers,
                }).subscribe(data => {
                    resolve(data.json());
                }, err => {
                    reject(err);
                });
            });
        });
    }

    post(url: string, data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let headers = new Headers();
            this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers).then(() => {
                return this.http.post(url, data, {
                    headers: headers,
                }).subscribe(output => {
                    resolve(output.json());
                }, err => {
                    reject(err);
                });
            });
        });
    }

    private createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers): Promise<void> {
        console.log('creating auth header');
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.storage.get('username')
                .then( username => {
                    this.storage.get('password')
                        .then( password => {
                            headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
                                btoa(username + ':' + password));
                            resolve();
                        });
                });
        });
    }
}
```

The other components are using `hasLoggedIn()` function to check if we are logged in or not when switching back to the App. If not logged in anymore (storage cleaned in any way) we get back to the LoginPage component.

Comment: Thanks to this person that down voted my Question, without leaving a message about what actually made him/her doing this.

Comment: Could you provide us with some code ? maybe your implementing local storage incorrectly

Comment: @LeRoy Hope this helps a bit more :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was a session header in the response that I somehow didn't see beforehand.

My solution is a simple Cookies clearing:

```
window.cookies.clear(function() {});
```

Comment: What is `window` in that statement? How do you get hold of it in your Ionic app?